# How to handle both token based and cookie based authentication on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cookies, devise, token

I am building a mobile app that authenticates to a rails server using token authentication. I am using Devise for authentication and have figured out a way to make it work on mobile. But I also have a web app. The web app is not consuming json API but it's just a regular rails web app.

Now the problem is I want to be able to use token based authentication for mobile, but at the same time allow users to sign in via web interface.

How can I make this work?

Comment: I am also interested in a solution. I believe devise can handle both types but I don't think it can simultaneously check for tokens and cookie.

Comment: See these solutions. http://www.refaelos.com/post/20664288136/multiple-token-authentication-with-devise-redis?2c914400 http://shortround.net/2012/10/03/handling-multiple-authentication-types-in-rails/